# Функции в гугл таблицах (работа с временем)

Tags: база-данных, функции, время, google-spreadsheet, статистика

Вопрос следующий. Есть гугл таблица куда модераторы записывают данные о пользователях сайта. С помощью фунции COUNTIFS сортируются необходимые данные. Вопрос следующий - необходимы 2 временные функции. Сортировка данных исключительно в Current date (https://www.screencast.com/t/0k5emCbyuLn). И вторая функция отдельно что бы меняла фон или выбеделяла даты в таблице (строна дата/время) по логике (Current date -3 days) для того, что бы модераторы помнили о кейсах которые необходимо обработать.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почему так мало - всего две функции? Размещались бы уже вопросов с десяток...

Comment: Потому что такова жизнь Виктор. У меня есть вопрос по 2-м функциям. У вас нет ответа ни по одной. Увы

Comment: Нет, у Вас под одной крышей РАЗНЫЕ ВОПРОСЫ. У меня могут быть ответы. Но помогать там, где помощь только одному и этот один не хочет помочь другим, неинтересно. Один вопрос - одна тема. Озаглавливать вопрос следует так, чтобы была понятна конкретная задача. Показать пример, на котором можно проверять решение... Так и помощники подтянутся.

Comment: Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic